# PHP URL Rewrite two parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess, email

Is it possible to have an url like `www.domain.com/admin/mail-sent` which actually would be `www.domain.com/admin/mail.php?category=mail&folder=sent`?

I have this set up in my .htaccess:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ mail.php?category=$1folder=$2
```

.. and I don't know if it's right. I've tried with just the folder as the URL which was fine, but I really want the url to be like `/mail-sent` instead of just `/sent`.

Is this even possible?

Have a wonderful day :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is:

```
RewriteRule ^admin/([^-]+)-([^/]+)/?$ mail.php?category=$1&folder=$2 [L,NC]
```

`([^-]+)` anything not a dash

`([^/]+)` anything not a `/` after the first dash

You can also do it more strictly like:

```
RewriteRule ^admin/(mail)-(sent)/?$ mail.php?category=$1&folder=$2 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Yes, that works perfectly. But if I for example want to setup a query with those parameters, then it fails. My query looks like this: `$db->query("SELECT * FROM mail WHERE category = '".$_GET['category']."' AND folder = '".$_GET['folder']."'");` then it wont return the results. But if I use just one parameter like `folder=inbox` then it works just fine. Or if i put in `category = 'mail' AND folder = 'inbox'` in the query, then it works just fine as well..

Comment: @dinkode.dk rule was missing `&` to separate the parameter as it was partially copy of your post. Check now.

Comment: Just added the & sign. But it still doesn't work.. When I `print $_GET['category'];` and type in mail-inbox, then it just print this `$` instead of mail which it should do..

Answer (score 0):

Sure, it's possible. Just rewrite your regex to watch out for `-`. With parenthesis you can define matching groups:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\-([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ mail.php?category=$1folder=$2
```

$1 refers to first parenthesis, $2 to second.